# Alfresco Community edition 7.4 - Tomcat service Issue

Tags: alfresco, tomcat9, alfresco-share

I have installed the alfresco community edition 7.4 and its running through the command prompt. When the tomcat service registered from the windows service its throwing the below error,

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'keyStore' defined in class path resource [alfresco/encryption-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 01260001 Failed to initialize keystore:    Location: C:/alfresco-community/alf_data/keystore/keystore   Provider: null   Type:     JCEKS
2024-02-26T15:41:11,985 [] ERROR [web.context.ContextLoader] [main] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'keyStore' defined in class path resource [alfresco/encryption-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 01260001 Failed to initialize keystore: 
   Location: C:/alfresco-community/alf_data/keystore/keystore
   Provider: null
   Type:     JCEKS
```

Checked the config files

Comment: Your question seems to be more about starting Tomcat via Windows service than about Alfresco. First, try to understand the setup of your Windows service and compare it to your startup script to find out the difference. Then share your findings here so others can help you. s. https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html